# how to remove last comma (,) from this string without using built-in functions like "rtrim" and "substr"

Tags: php, function

How to remove last comma (,) from array?
without using inbuilt functions like  rtrim and substr

```
    public function update( $table_name="", $fields_value=array(), $where="" ){
    //if( $table_name == "" || empty($fields_value) ||  $where == "" ) return false; 

    $fields_values = array(
        'name' => 'Vikrant',
        'class' => 'MCA',
        'Section' => 'a',
        'Subject' => 'Ele'
    );

    $column_value_string = "";
    foreach( $fields_values as $col_name => $col_value ) {
        $column_value_string .= " `$col_name`='$col_value' ,";
    }
    echo rtrim($column_value_string,",")."<br><br><br><br>";
    return;
```

Comment: Why? It's like asking "how can I hammer a nail without using a hammer or any other kind of blunt instrument?".

Comment: May we know why ? If you have in-built functions then take advantage of that. That will be time consuming.

Comment: i just want to explore code .
if you know please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a comma-seprated list, put things into an array and then `implode` it:

```
$column_value = array();
foreach( $fields_values as $col_name => $col_value ) {
    $column_value []= "`$col_name`='$col_value'";
}
$column_value_string = implode(", ", $column_value);
```

Also do note that you must escape values when generating SQL commands dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can done this  with counter in your loop Try

```
$fields_values = array(
        'name' => 'Vikrant',
        'class' => 'MCA',
        'Section' => 'a',
        'Subject' => 'Ele'
);
$count = count($fields_values);
$i=1;
$column_value_string = "";
foreach( $fields_values as $col_name => $col_value ) {
  $column_value_string .= " `$col_name`='$col_value'";
  if($i <$count) {
    $column_value_string .= ',';
  }
  $i++;
}
echo  $column_value_string;
```

output :-

```
`name`='Vikrant', `class`='MCA', `Section`='a', `Subject`='Ele'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = explode(",",$ TheArray);
 $array = implode(",", $array);
```

Short, simple.. does the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = 'test,';
    if($str[strlen($str) - 1 ] == ',') $str[strlen($str) - 1] = null;
    echo $str; // test
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help you......



    public function update( $table_name="", $fields_value=array(), $where="" ){ 

    $fields_values = array(
        'name' => 'Vikrant',
        'class' => 'MCA',
        'Section' => 'a',
        'Subject' => 'Ele'
    );
    $column_value_string = array();
    foreach( $fields_values as $col_name => $col_value ) {
        $column_value_string[] = " `$col_name`='$col_value'";
    }
    echo implode(',',$column_value_string);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve desired result by following

```
public function update( $table_name="", $fields_value=array(), $where="" ){
    //if( $table_name == "" || empty($fields_value) ||  $where == "" ) return false; 

    $fields_values = array(
        'name' => 'Vikrant',
        'class' => 'MCA',
        'Section' => 'a',
        'Subject' => 'Ele'
    );

    $column_value_string = "";
    foreach( $fields_values as $col_name => $col_value ) {
        $column_value_string .= ($column_value_string == ""?'':', ')." `$col_name`='$col_value'";
    }
    echo $column_value_string."<br><br><br><br>";
    return;
}
```

Comment: why this answer? rtrim() is used in this

Comment: @Khushboo if you can see rtrim is not required.... the result is achieved the step before it... rtrim is not going to make any change...

Comment: @Khushboo :: please use inbuilt  functions